# Problem between Sidewaystable and page header

Tags: floats, header-footer, rotating

I've a table too large for the regular width page. Using the package [`rotating`](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/rotating), I was able to set it in landscape orientation. Using the package is not the problem, the problem is that I'm using a FANCY header in the entire document and actually I'm having and undesired overlapping between the header and the table, as the photo shows.

[image]

I've tried the following two options:

1. Using the `\thispagestyle{empty}` command in order to remove the header just in that page. The problem is that I don't know how to fix the page to be modified, so I get a blank style page different to the one I need to blank.
2. I tried to use the [`adjustbox`](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/adjustbox) package, but as far as I know, the package works for normal orientation, right?

Comment: You can play with `\tabcolsep`, which is 6pt by default. Could you post a minimal example?

Answer (score 1):

Package `fancyhdr` offers you the `\iffloatpage` command to specify different settings for headers/footers in float only pages (as the ones produced when using `sidewaystable`); the syntax is

```
\iffloatpage{<value for float only pages>}{<value other pages>}
```

A complete example, which you can easily adapt to your settings, in which I suppressed the header and the headrule for float only pages:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{rotating}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhf{}
\fancyhead[C]{\iffloatpage{}{\leftmark}}
\renewcommand\headrulewidth{\iffloatpage{0pt}{0.4pt}}

\begin{document}

\section{Test section one}
\lipsum[1-2]
\begin{sidewaystable}
\begin{tabular}{@{}p{\textwidth}@{}}
\lipsum[2]
\end{tabular}
\caption{test rotated table}
\end{sidewaystable}
\lipsum[1-6]

\end{document}
```

The output:

[image]