# Rotated table overlapping with page header

Tags: tables, rotating

I have a problem similar to:

[Problem between Sidewaystable and page header](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/229472/problem-between-sidewaystable-and-page-header)

I want to insert some blank space above the vbox such that the table isn't overlapping with the page header.

Due to GDPR I can't share my table but It's on the below form:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{adjustbox}
\usepackage{rotating}

\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{lastpage}
\pagestyle{fancy}

\fancypagestyle{documentstyle}{
    \fancyhf{} % clear all header and footer fields
    \renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0.2pt}
    \lhead{\textit{Section 1}}
    \rhead{\textit{Name}}
    \cfoot{\thepage\ of \pageref{LastPage}}
}


\begin{document}

\newpage\pagestyle{documentstyle}

\setlength{\tabcolsep}{0.1cm}
\rotatebox{90}{
\vbox{
\begin{table}[H]
\centering
\begin{adjustbox}{width=1.5\textwidth,center=\textwidth}
\tiny
\begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|}
\hline
1& 1& 1& 1& 1& 1& 1& 1& 1& 1& 1& 1& 1& 1&1\\ \hline
1& 1& 1& 1& 1& 1& 1& 1& 1& 1& 1& 1& 1& 1&1\\ \hline
\end{tabular}
\end{adjustbox}
\end{table}
}}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Your code produces an error on my machine.

Comment: Anyway, you should never use `adjustbox`  for tables, as it leads to fontsize inconsistencies.

Comment: @Schrödinger'scat, I updated the latex part, and it should work now.

Comment: @Bernard Thank you for your comment, I was wondering, why it changed the size of the text when ```adjustbox``` was added. I use ```adjustbox``` to move the caption relative to the table, my table is so large that the difference between ```\tiny``` when using ```adjustbox``` and not using ```adjustbox``` is so small that I prefer using ```adjustbox``` in this case.

Comment: You have  several better solutions, but it's impossible to propose whatever without a representative example. Among the solutions, if there are many columns, reducing the value of `tabcolsep` (6pt by default, and there are two of them between two  adjacent columns), using multilined cells and of course, reducing the font size (in my opinion, under \footnotesize, it gets unreadable – and very likely unread.

Comment: My table is quite complex,  and have have multiple merged cells. I may post a question regarding better solutions regarding the table setup. For now I'm just interested in moving the table down, such that it is non-overlapping with the page header.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use `sidewaystable`. The table will be in the center of the text area as long as it is smaller than it:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{rotating}

\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{lastpage}
\pagestyle{fancy}

\fancypagestyle{documentstyle}{
    \fancyhf{} % clear all header and footer fields
    \renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0.2pt}
    \lhead{\textit{Section 1}}
    \rhead{\textit{Name}}
    \cfoot{\thepage\ of \pageref{LastPage}}
}

\begin{document}
\pagestyle{documentstyle}

\begin{sidewaystable}
    \centering
\begin{tabular}{|c|c| c|c| c|c| c|c| c|c| c|c| c|c| c|}
    \hline
1& 2& 3& 4& 5& 6& 7& 8& 9& 10& 11& 12& 13& 14& 15\\ \hline
1& 1& 1& 1& 1& 1& 1& 1& 1& 1& 1& 1& 1& 1&1\\ \hline
\end{tabular}
\end{sidewaystable}

\end{document}
```

[image]